# Auto-deleted posts from spammers and trolls should get the "this is spam/rude" warning

Tags: feature-request, spam, offensive, deleted-posts, account-destruction

When a **post** is deleted by spam or rude/abusive flags, users who can see deleted posts see a warning along the lines of "this post was deleted as spam or offensive".  If they want to see the actual post, they have to click through.  Many 10k users on my sites appreciate this shielding.

When a **user** is destroyed with the "created to post spam or nonsense" reason, all posts from that user are automatically deleted.  This gives moderators a quick way to purge all the bad content.  (Sometimes these users manage to post several times before being caught.)

However, these auto-deleted posts don't get the special shielding, even though the user was deleted for spamming.  Maybe that's because we don't want to shield the pure-garbage posts we sometimes see; those aren't offensive, just garbage.  We don't have a destruction reason for "offensive", and spam and offensive are often treated the same way, so this is the reason that moderators use.

One of my sites has been getting a lot of *very* offensive troll posts recently.  The posts get deleted quickly, but I'd like our 10k users to not have to see them either.  It seems logical to me that if a user was destroyed for being a spammer or troll, then when we auto-delete the posts we should treat them as if they had been individually flagged.

Can we treat posts that were deleted for being rude or spam the same way regardless of how they got deleted?

Comment: This can be implemented by spam-deleting instead of normally deleting posts when a user is destroyed.